# Building signed release apk in flutter with gradle 4 fails

Tags: java, flutter, dart, android-manifest, javadoc

Only when I upgrade to **Gradle 4**...
and Only when I try to build a **signed** **release apk** ...
(building aab is working fine),
I get the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:profileRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
```

I know that the problem can skipped by adding :

```
lintOptions {
 checkReleaseBuilds false
 abortOnError false
}
```

but I don't want to do this, so I analyzed the errors by Inspect Code, and found that I have 3 error:

**in AndroidManifest.xml:**

> Unresolved class 'FacebookActivity'

> Unresolved class 'CustomTabActivity'

**in Javadoc:**
Declaration has problems in javadoc references

> GoogleSignInPlugin 1 error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Delegate'

SCREENSHOTS:
[image]

[image]

I upgraded both packages at pubspec.yaml and ran flutter clean & flutter pub cache repair, but nothing changed.